# css round corners

Tags: css, image, html, repeat

I have three images. One for the left, one for the right and one for the middle. 
This is what i have:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 img {border:0}

.bl {background: url(images/backer_left.gif) top left no-repeat; height:47px; }
.br {background: url(images/backer_right.gif) top right no-repeat; height:47px;}
.tr {background: url(images/backer_alt.gif) ; margin:0 4px 0 4px; font-size:12px; height:47px;}
.trText { padding:10px; } 
.clear { clear:both; }
</style>
<div class="bl">
  <div class="br">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="trText">lay lay lomm</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>  
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

i cannot see the left and the right images. just the repeating backer_alt.gif. what am i doing wrong? 
thx

edited
this version works:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 img {border:0}

 .bl {background: url(images/backer_left.gif) top left no-repeat; height:47px; }
 .br {background: url(images/backer_right.gif) top right no-repeat; height:47px;}
 .tr {background: url(images/backer_alt.gif) ; margin:0 4px 0 4px; font-size:12px; height:47px;}
   .trText { padding:10px; } 
 .clear { clear:both; }
 </style>
<div class="bl">
    <div class="br">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="trText">lay lay lomm</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using the CSS `border-radius` style? It's so much simpler.

Comment: i don't think it's supported by the earlier versions of IE.

Comment: It's not. But these days I really fight for not spending this much time and this much code and that much bandwidth to fix something in an buggy old browser that really has no bearing on the overall usability of the site. You can't always win that argument, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `.tr`’s `margin` to 10px instead of its `padding`. You also probably need to set the `background-position` on `.br` to `top right` so it appears in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

As noah says, adding the correct margin left & right to the .tr, depending corner width,
will make it appears:

```
.bl {background: url(images/backer_left.gif) no-repeat left top; }
.br {background: url(images/backer_right.gif) no-repeat right top; }
.tr {background: url(images/backer_alt.gif) repeat-x; margin:0 10px; padding:10 0; }
```